# AutoIt - Return value always 0

Tags: return-value, autoit

I wrote a method that can be recursive, but the return value is always 0, even when it has a value as a string on the console:

```
Func hasItTheThing($s)

$result = StringInStr(...,...)
local $newstring

$newstring = $s

If NOT $result > 0 Then

ConsoleWrite("newstring = " & $newstring & @CRLF)
return $newstring

Else


$newstring = ;Fix something with the string
hasItTheThing($newstring)


EndIf


EndFunc
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, your bug that caused the always zero result:  The "Else" branch of your IF (If NOT $result > 0) has no return.  So when result > 0, your function calls itself but when that returns a value, it is discarded and the function continues to the exit, returning nothing.

The fix:

```
...
Else
    $newstring = ;Fix something with the string
    return hasItTheThing($newstring)   ; <== Added a "return" here
EndIf
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, nevermind, http://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/Recursion
answered this.

I solved it by replacing the keyword return with a local variable that is declared outside the function, and set the value to this variable.